# How to add gzip to react app with create-react-app command

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gzip

I am new to react programming. I created a react app with create-react-app command. For generating build i am running npm run build command(react-scripts build). Build size of my application is 2.5 MB, i wanted to reduce the app size. I looked in SO, found some people are using webpack and gzip plugins to reduce the app size. But if you generate react app with create-react-app command we can't see webpack configurations until and unless npm run eject. So is there any way to add gzip compression to my react web app.

Comment: You need to run the eject script and modify the web pack config file

Comment: After doing eject i can see webpack.config in node modules. I need to add this webpack configuratons there right\

Comment: Yes, see my answer, also I recommend you to use webpack-bundle-analyzer, It help you see the content of the bundle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [compression-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression-webpack-plugin)

Add it in your `webpack.config.js` file

```
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
            
module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
 ...
 return {
    plugins: [
        ...
        isEnvProduction && 
            new CompressionPlugin({
              algorithm: "gzip",
              test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
              threshold: 10240,
              minRatio: 0.8
            }),
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: hey after doing this build folder contains .gz and .js, server side do i need to do any changes

Comment: But my .js file size inside build folder same 2.3MB but my .gz file size is 670kb

Comment: Yes, you need to activate this option in your server, that way the server will return de gz file and not the js file. That config depends of which server are you using.